# How to play Background Music on loop in a game with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, loops, audio, background, playback

Coding a game on Flutter, Want to play music on loop in Background when the app starts with audioplayers: ^0.20.1 package and WidgetsBindingObserver, doesn't work! The audio doesn't play.

The other ".wav" format works fine with "AudioCache". But "AudioCache" doesn't have pause and resume properties. So tired of "AudioPlayer" and the ".mp3" extension audio doesn't play. But the same ".mp3" extension audio plays with "AudioCache".

Check the Code Below

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bugbee2/barrier.dart';
import 'package:bugbee2/bee.dart';
import 'package:bugbee2/coverScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  // bee variables
  static double beeY = 0;
  double initialPos = beeY;
  double height = 0;
  double time = 0;
  double gravity = -4.9; // how strong the gravity is
  double velocity = 3.5; // how strong the jump is
  double beeWidth = 0.1; // out of 2, 2 being the entire width of the screen
  double beeHeight = 0.1; // out of 2, 2 being the entire height of the screen
  // inciment score
  int score = 0;
  int bestScore = 0;

  // game settings
  bool gameHasStarted = false;

  // Best Score Value Update
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkBestScore();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  }

// Remove Observer
  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Background Music

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      player.play("sounds/tea-ceremony.mp3");
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      player.pause();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      player.pause();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      player.stop();
    }
  }

  // Saving Best Score
  getBestScore() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int bestScore = prefs.getInt('bestScore') ?? 0;
    return bestScore;
  }

  setBestScore() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('bestScore', bestScore);
  }

  // barrier variables
  static List<double> barrierX = [2, 2 + 1.5];
  static double barrierWidth = 0.5; // out of 2
  List<List<double>> barrierHeight = [
    // out of 2, where 2 is the entire height of the screen
    // [topHeight, bottomHeight]
    [0.6, 0.4],
    [0.4, 0.6],
  ];

  void startGame() {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play(
      "sounds/jump.wav",
    );
    gameHasStarted = true;
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
      // a real physical jump is the same as an upside down parabola
      // so this is a simple quadratic equation
      height = gravity * time * time + velocity * time;

      setState(() {
        beeY = initialPos - height;
      });

      // check if bird is dead
      if (beeIsDead()) {
        timer.cancel();
        _showDialog();
        final player = AudioCache();
        player.play(
          "sounds/slide-hit.wav",
        );
      }

      // keep the map moving (move barriers)
      moveMap();

      // keep the time going!
      time += 0.01;
    });
  }

  void moveMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < barrierX.length; i++) {
      // keep barriers moving
      setState(() {
        barrierX[i] -= 0.005;
      });

      // if barrier exits the left part of the screen, keep it looping
      if (barrierX[i] < -1.5) {
        barrierX[i] += 3;
        score++;
        final player = AudioCache();
        player.play(
          "sounds/coin-touch.wav",
        );
        setBestScore();
        if (score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = score;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  checkBestScore() async {
    int tempBestScore = await getBestScore() ?? 0;
    setState(() {
      bestScore = tempBestScore;
    });
  }

  void resetGame() {
    Navigator.pop(context); // dismisses the alert dialog
    setState(() {
      beeY = 0;
      gameHasStarted = false;
      time = 0;
      initialPos = beeY;
      barrierX = [2, 2 + 1.5];
      score = 0;
    });
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "G A M E  O V E R",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: resetGame,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      'PLAY AGAIN',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.brown),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void jump() {
    final player = AudioCache();
    player.play(
      "sounds/jump.wav",
    );
    setState(() {
      time = 0;
      initialPos = beeY;
    });
  }

  bool beeIsDead() {
    // check if the bird is hitting the top or the bottom of the screen
    if (beeY < -1 || beeY > 1) {
      return true;
    }

    // hits barriers
    // checks if bird is within x coordinates and y coordinates of barriers
    for (int i = 0; i < barrierX.length; i++) {
      if (barrierX[i] <= beeWidth &&
          barrierX[i] + barrierWidth >= -beeWidth &&
          (beeY <= -1 + barrierHeight[i][0] ||
              beeY + beeHeight >= 1 - barrierHeight[i][1])) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: gameHasStarted ? jump : startGame,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue.shade500,
                child: Center(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      // bird
                      MyBee(
                        beeY: beeY,
                        beeWidth: beeWidth,
                        beeHeight: beeHeight,
                      ),

                      // tap to play
                      MyCoverScreen(gameHasStarted: gameHasStarted),

                      MyBarrier(
                        barrierX: barrierX[0],
                        barrierWidth: barrierWidth,
                        barrierHeight: barrierHeight[0][0],
                        isThisBottomBarrier: false,
                      ),

                      // Bottom barrier 0
                      MyBarrier(
                        barrierX: barrierX[0],
                        barrierWidth: barrierWidth,
                        barrierHeight: barrierHeight[0][1],
                        isThisBottomBarrier: true,
                      ),

                      // Top barrier 1
                      MyBarrier(
                        barrierX: barrierX[1],
                        barrierWidth: barrierWidth,
                        barrierHeight: barrierHeight[1][0],
                        isThisBottomBarrier: false,
                      ),

                      // Bottom barrier 1
                      MyBarrier(
                        barrierX: barrierX[1],
                        barrierWidth: barrierWidth,
                        barrierHeight: barrierHeight[1][1],
                        isThisBottomBarrier: true,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.brown,
                child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            score.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'S C O R E',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            bestScore.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 35),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'B E S T',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using audioplayers: ^ 0.19.1

```
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  AudioCache audioCache;
  String audioCorrect = "audio/access_granted.mp3";
```

I have this method that call in initState()

```
 void initPlayer() {
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);
  }
```

I play the audio this way

```
  audioCache.play(audioCorrect);
```