# How to implement audio service with audioplayers flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, audio-service

Below code shows how i am using audioplayers without audio service

```
playFromFile(List textList, seek) async {
    for (int i = seek; i < textList.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        newSeek = i;
      });
      itemScrollController.scrollTo(
          index: i,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
      String text = textList[i].join(' ');
      final bytes = await getAudio(text);
      await audioPlugin.playBytes(bytes);
      while (audioPlugin.state == PlayerState.PLAYING && !playFresh) {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        if (audioPlugin.state == PlayerState.PLAYING) {
          audioPlugin.onPlayerCompletion.listen((onDone) async {
            audioPlugin.state = PlayerState.COMPLETED;
            await audioPlugin.release();
          });
        }
        if (audioPlugin.state == PlayerState.COMPLETED) {
          await audioPlugin.release();
          break;
        }
      }

      if (playFresh) break;
    }
  }
```

I want to implement this code using audio service so i can play audio in background . How to implement this with audio service so it will play in background. Please help as i am new to flutter and unable to solve this for days.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686068/how-to-play-background-music-on-loop-in-a-game-with-flutter/70686754#70686754

Answer (score 1):

Solution will be quite simple.
You implement this using different layer.

UI Layer - This will be your UI from where you going to click the play button.

Intermediate layer or Audio service Layer(Audio service class) - From your UI layer you going to called this audio service class play method.

Final layer (Actual audio player methods) - This will be final layer where your actual audio package mehtods resides. You called this layer from your intermediate layer.

Summary - UI layer play button -> Audio service Play method -> Audio player Play method